# ASP.NET MVC 5 API Application uses its own connection string instead of the referred applications connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a solution that contains 2 applications

- Application (.NET Application)
- ApiApplication (Console Application)

Within Application I have this controller:

```
public class ApiAccountController : Controller
{
    ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
    Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    PasswordHasher passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher();

    // GET: Account
    public bool AuthenticateUser(String username, String password)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
            //var user = dbContext.Users.Count(u => u.UserName == username);
            if (user == null)
            {
                log.Error(username + " not found");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user.PasswordHash, password);
                if (result == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    log.Error("Invalid password for user: " + username);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            //return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error(e, "Exception found for user: " + username);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Within ApiApplication I have this Api Class:

```
public class TokenController : ApiController
{
    // This is naive endpoint for demo, it should use Basic authentication to provide token or POST request
    // GET api/token/
    public string Get(string username, string password)
    {
        if (CheckUser(username, password))
        {
            return JwtManager.GenerateToken(username);
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }

    private bool CheckUser(string username, string password)
    {
        ApiAccountController accountController = new ApiAccountController();
        return accountController.AuthenticateUser(username,password);
    }
}
```

ApiApplication references Application and I want to call AuthenticateUser from Application. Previously when I tried to run it, AuthenticateUser would always return null, I managed to narrow it down to something to do with my dbContext. However, I discovered that when I placed the connectionstring from Application into ApiApplication, I get an error that says my database already exists.

The purpose of ApiApplication is only to receive and pass requests to Application and to retrieve data from ApiApplication. It should not be connected to the database at all. Am I missing something? Should I specify the connectionString for Application when ApiApplication calls the AuthenticateUser method?

Comment: I guess you miss a lot...There is no way your Api is calling your Application. Your application is maybe a library project, and your wizards created some connection strings in the app.config of your project. But as your startup project is your apo application the connection string should be set there.

Comment: Thank you. My startup project is Application. My ApiApplication references Application and calls the AuthenticateUser class. And thank you for changing it. I will remember it next time.